# Random Tables in a dag fail in the create table stage with filenotfound : beeline error

Tags: hive, airflow, bitnami, beeline

The create table stage -

`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aa_db_aaa_prod.BASE` (`UpdatedByName` STRING, `UpdatedOn` BIGINT, `UpdatedOnTimeZoneOffset` INTEGER); ``

```
 ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
 packages/cloudera/cdp/airflow/operators/cdw_operator.py", line 108, in execute
 self.hook.run_cli(hql=self.hql, schema=self.schema, hive_conf=self.hiveconfs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/cloudera/cdp/airflow/hooks/cdw_hook.py", line 204, in run_cli
    sub_process = subprocess.Popen(
   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
   self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
   raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'beeline'
```

However, my confusion is, this is not new installation and nothing has changed. Also, other tables in the dag are successful. Beeline connection through the cli on airflow server with same user is successful. I cant understand the cause for this error ? Any leads on this please ?

Comment: seems like the CT statement has an extra backtick ``` before UpdatedByName. Pls try this "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aa_db_aaa_prod`.`BASE` (`UpdatedByName` STRING, `UpdatedOn` BIGINT, `UpdatedOnTimeZoneOffset` INTEGER);"  and let me know?

Comment: Hiya, sorry its a typo in this post, code doesn't have the extra backtick.

Comment: i can see one more problem in syntax. You mentioned  `aa_db_aaa_prod.BASE`, whereas correct code should be  `aa_db_aaa_prod`.`BASE`  - individually backticked.

Comment: Also - do you have RW access on  database - aa_db_aaa_prod?

Comment: Hiya, The cause  was, /repos/cloudera/parcels/CDH/bin/beeline got removed on one of the airflow node, which was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was, /repos/cloudera/parcels/CDH/bin/beeline got removed on one of the airflow node, which was causing this issue.